# How to concatenate and store MYSQL column values?

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

How do i concatenate a number of SQL columns and store the result in a result column? I am presently testing it using the following code:

```
***TEST.PHP***
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

$result = mysql_query('SELECT concat(q1, q2) as result FROM assessment WHERE assessmentid = 32');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 echo $row['result'];
  }

?>
```

In my assessment table, I have the following columns:
`assessmentid | q1 | q2 | result`

In q1, there is the value of 3 in q1, and 5 in q2 therefore 35 is being echo'ed. I'm unsure on how I can add this result to my database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assessmentid | q1 | q2 | result

UPDATE assessment set `result` = CONCAT(`q1`, `q2`) where condition
```

Comment: You genius, I was on the same lines but this cleared it up for me. Thanks Akam

Answer (score 0):

i don't think i fully understand you question.... if i didnt understand maybe you can explain better what you want?

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT concat(q1, q2) as result FROM 
assessment WHERE assessmentid = 32');

$q1=mysql_result($result,0,"q1");
$q2=mysql_result($result,0,"q2");

$concat = $q1 . $q2 ;
$query = "INSERT INTO assessment (result) VALUES
('$concat')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("error");
```